# DrawRect never being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, drawrect

I put this code in my app:

```
-(void)setup {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"Test 1");

}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Test 2");
}
```

I get a bunch of Test 1s on the NSLog (because this is a UITableViewCell), but no Test 2s at any point.

Comment: you should show us code or explain how you you instantiate and use the class. is it a class or a category? ...

Comment: I had the frame height set to 0; apparently that meant it didn't call drawrect.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the sample project TableViewSuite (CustomTableViewCell project) here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html 
I was able to add your log statement into the TimeZoneCell class and was able to get output.  Taking a look at this might help answer your question?

```
#import "TimeZoneCell.h"
#import "TimeZoneWrapper.h"
#import "TimeZoneView.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCellAppDelegate.h"


@implementation TimeZoneCell

@synthesize timeZoneView;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        // Create a time zone view and add it as a subview of self's contentView.
        CGRect tzvFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height);
        timeZoneView = [[TimeZoneView alloc] initWithFrame:tzvFrame];
        timeZoneView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.contentView addSubview:timeZoneView];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Test 2");
}

- (void)setTimeZoneWrapper:(TimeZoneWrapper *)newTimeZoneWrapper {
    // Pass the time zone wrapper to the view
    timeZoneView.timeZoneWrapper = newTimeZoneWrapper;
}


- (void)redisplay {
    [timeZoneView setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [timeZoneView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```